# Thought experiment about limit of random sequence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I recently thought of an interesting conjecture, but I have no idea how to prove it. Suppose you have some random function $r(x)$, where $x\geq0$, that evaluates to some random value on the interval $[0,x]$. This random function can follow any arbitrary distribution, as I don't believe it will affect the conjecture. Now define a sequence $a_n$, where $a_n=r(a_{n-1})$. My conjecture is that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$. That is, a sequence where every term is randomly distributed between $0$ and the previous term will inevitably go to zero. I'm currently taking a course in probability and statistics, and was wondering if this is true, and if so how it can be proven.

Comment: The distribution $\delta_x$?

Comment: Certainly, you want the $r(x) < x$ (strict inequality), otherwise a constant sequence would satisfy your hypotheses, and we can certainly engineer a distribution to produce that sequence.

Comment: D'oh, same comment as you, @user10354138, but you get the medal for brevity. :-)

Comment: @SammyBlack Also I don't think merely $r(x)<x$ is enough to guarantee $\lim a_n=0$.  There are some obvious constructions using Cantor set.

Comment: I agree. I was trying not to say too much.